# How can i modify a input number field by click of a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to increase the value in input text field when a button is clicked but to be honest i dont know correct way since i am a newbie to javascript. i have done this much.

```
function input1()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("box").value;
    document.getElementById("box").innnerHTML= x*10+1 ;
}
```

but its not working.
here is the html of the input field.

```
<input type="number" name="display" id="box"style="height:55px;font-size:25px;text-align:end;">
```

Comment: thanks, everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
function input1()
{
    var x = +document.getElementById("box").value;
    document.getElementById("box").value= x*10+1 ;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a summary of your changes to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Input tags do not have innerHTML; use the value property if you want to reassign text in an input.

```
function input1()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("box").value;
    document.getElementById("box").value = x * 10 + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value with

```
document.getElementById("box").value = x*10+1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function input1() {
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    box.value = box.value * 10 + 1;
}
```

Also, I added "value=0" to your HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="display" id="box" value="0" style="height:55px;font-size:25px;text-align:end;">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/xxyjoLa7/1/